# Overrule previous redirect_to in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, activeadmin, ruby-on-rails-4.1

Given the following simplified situation (in reality, the scenario is from an ActiveAdmin backed app):

```
class ShapeController < ApplicationController
  def update
    (...)
    redirect_to
  end
end

class CircleController < ShapeController
  def update
    super
    (...)
    redirect_to
  end
end
```

Calling `CircleController#update` will cause the famous "AbstractController::DoubleRenderError" because `redirect_to` is called twice.

Now, I can't prevent the first call of `redirect_to` by `super`, at least not without messing with ActiveAdmin's code. Is there another way to cancel the first `redirect_to` and overrule it with another one?

Thanks for your hints!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveAdmin is using [Inherited Resources](https://github.com/josevalim/inherited_resources) to do perform the standard REST actions. The gem provided a way to overwrite the respond_to block. I've never try this before but this might be helpful in your case:

```
ActiveAdmin.register Circle do
  # ... 

  controller do
    def update
      update! do |success, failure|
        failure.html { redirect_to circle_url(@circle) }
      end
    end
  end

  # ...
end
```

Refer to the IR gem documentation for more options to overwrite the actions(under Overwriting actions section).

Answer (score 0):

I would say it is not possible. The best solution would be to extract the action code in some protected controller method, and call it from the child controller:

```
class ShapeController < ApplicationController
  def update
    do_the_update
    redirect_to
  end

  protected

  def do_the_update
    # your code
  end
end

class CircleController < ShapeController
  def update
    do_the_update
    redirect_to
  end
end
```

Comment: As I said, I know how to fix this in ShapeController. But since that would be inside the ActiveAdmin gem, I'm looking for another solution.

Comment: @svoop: i guess there is no solution then, sorry